# How to retrieve value "null value not allowed" from Rest assured JSON response in java

Tags: arrays, json, rest, validation, rest-assured

I am not able to retrieve `"null value not allowed"` from below `JSON` response array in Rest assured java.

```
[

    {
        "0": [
            {
                "amount": [
                    "null value not allowed"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.`enter code here`

If any reusable function could be more useful.

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: Please add your sample code that you've tried! You'd probably be looking for something along the lines of .then().extract().response().jsonPath().get("[0].0[0].amount[0]") after your .post()/.get()/.patch() etc

Comment: Thanks Steven for reply, below code i am used, got response and now i need to work on response to validate String stringResponse = res.asString();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(stringResponse);
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);